# How to use godoc for documentation

Tags: go, document, godoc

In one of my classes we have to use godoc to document our Go code. The code that we are using for the class is from a GitHub repo that we had to fork to our repo. Then from our repo I cloned it to a local repo. Every time I try to create the documentation using

```
godoc -http=:6060 &
```

it won't update. Is it because it was forked from someone else repo? I was under the belief that it would document the local repo.

Comment: Did you kill the previous background process?

Answer (score 0):

Is this project a go module and you placed it outside of `GOPATH`? If so, that's probable that you have old version of `godoc` installed, that doesn't support go modules.

[Module support for godoc](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33655) was added only recently. You can install newest version by running `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`. Then, make sure to run `godoc` executable from `GOBIN`(by default it's set to `$GOROOT/bin`).

Answer (score 0):

Is the code exporting any functions? (public functions names start with a capital letter)

If your code is not exporting any functions you will not see the documentation being shown because the idea for godoc is to show the functions that can be used by others.

Comment: Use a snippet of code so the reader can understand better.

Comment: If you need any clarification or have some questions for OP(Original Poster) of the question., Add a comment on the question.